# How to split up data for UDP transfer (for video frames)

Tags: sockets, udp, video-streaming

I'm currently transferring my video frame data with a routine like this:

```
while(totalSendBytes < len) {
    sendBytes = sendto(s, buf+totalSendBytes, bytesToRead, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
    if(sendBytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        // handle error here
    }
    totalSendBytes += sendBytes;
}
```

this transfers all the data and i can display it, but it gets out of control after a while. Yes thats expected with UDP transferred chunks.
I've read that I need to implement some "packet" type and put the timestamp somewhere. What i don't understand is, do i have to put the timestamp and header into each chunk (like bytesToRead sized packet) or just in front of the whole frame data?

If someone can show me an example or has something to read about packetizing video data for somewhat "reliable" udp transfer i would be thankful.

Comment: Video streaming protocols, and the associated buffering, are non-trivial.